# How can we upgrade SQL Server 2008 R2 to 2012 with replication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, transactional-replication

We want to upgrade from SQL Server 2008 R2 to 2012, current production environment having multiple publishers and subscribers.

Comment: Start here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143699(v=sql.110).aspx